# Browser hangs because of angular $http function

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

This is my code.

```
<html>
<title>Doctor List</title>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/DoctorStay.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var d = new Date();
        var weekday = new Array(7);
        weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        weekday[5] = "Friday";
        weekday[6] = "Saturday";

        var app=angular.module('DListApp',[]);
        app.controller('DListCtrl',function($scope,$http){

        $http({
            method : "POST",
            url : "http://localhost:81/DoctorStayServiceAngular/model/getDoctorList.php",
            params:{"city":"Surat","special":"Dentist","offset":"0","gender":"Any","fees":"Any","page":"10","state":"Gujarat","country":"IN"}
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.DoctorDeatil = response.data;
        }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.DoctorDeatil = response.statusText;
        });

        $scope.booking= function(docid,addid){
            //return addid;
            $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: "http://localhost:81/DoctorStayServiceAngular/model/getDoctorBookingDetail.php",
                    //params:{"doctorid":docid,"addressid":addid,"day":weekday[d.getDay()]}
                    params:{"doctorid":docid}
                }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
        };

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ListMargin">
        <input type='hidden' id='current_page' />
        <input type='hidden' id='show_per_page' />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row" id="header"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 AreaScroll" id="area"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 pagination-sm" ng-app="DListApp" ng-controller="DListCtrl">
                <div id="list"  ng-repeat="x in DoctorDeatil">
                    <div class="row DocList">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div id="DocImg" class="col-sm-2">

                            </div>
                            <div id="DocDetail" class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <a href="{{ x.profile_url}}">Dr. {{ x.fname}} {{ x.lname}}.</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    {{ x.lname}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    {{ x.dredu}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    {{ x.drspec}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <a href="{{ x.clinic_url}}"> {{ x.clinicname}}.</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="DocAppoinment" class="col-sm-3">
                                {{booking(x.profileid,x.addressid)}}                                    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div >


    </div> -->

</body>
```

In `$scope.booking= function(docid,addid){}` function when i user `$http` function my browser hangs so much. This is my php code.

`<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
echo json_encode($_REQUEST['doctorid']);
?>`

I am not doing anything new then also I am facing problem.

[image: This is my console output]

**EDIT**

I've change booking function like this.

```
$scope.booking= function(docid,addid){
        i++;
        console.log(i);
        //console.log(addid);
        return addid;
        /*  $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "http://localhost:81/DoctorStayServiceAngular/model/getDoctorBookingDetail.php",
                //params:{"doctorid":docid,"addressid":addid,"day":weekday[d.getDay()]}
                params:{"doctorid":docid}
            }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                return response.data;
            });*/
    };
```

and in console I am getting this OP.

[image: Output]

why my booking function is executing 2 time? there should be only 1 to 10 in console log.

Comment: what console says?

Comment: it hangs so much that i can't get chance to click on console. :(

Comment: make the console opened before the request starts, press F12

Comment: what's your browser?

Comment: I've check my script in both Firefox and chrome.

Comment: ok then make sure the console is open before the request starts, you may have to make the request starts manually after a click event or timer

Comment: I've add console output, suggest someting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111710/discussion-between-archish-and-ayman-alkom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you explain me why you have done this inside **ng-repeat**:

```
<div id="DocAppoinment" class="col-sm-3">
{{booking(x.profileid,x.addressid)}}                                    
</div>
```

Comment: first i will get doctor list from first $http function and use loop to set those detail in div, in loop i will make another $http call to get booking detail of  doctor .

Comment: it is very simple thing
why you are calling another $http inside ng repeat for getting booking detail of doctors.

instead of this you should do 
ng-repeat="x in DoctorDeatil"
now DoctorDeatil would be the final scope which contain data of  DocAppoinment